# can generation of pressure create light?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, electrostatics, pressure

If pressure is applied on a body , can mechanical stress produce light? , as electrons are produced in piezoelectricty.
if yes , please answer or recommend any book/website/paper. 
Thank you

Comment: Possibly related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonoluminescence

Answer (score 1):

I can provide you with one phenomenon as an example for the question. It is called sonoluminescence.

> Sonoluminescence can occur when a sound wave of sufficient intensity
>   induces a gaseous cavity within a liquid to collapse quickly. This
>   cavity may take the form of a pre-existing bubble, or may be generated
>   through a process known as cavitation. Sonoluminescence in the
>   laboratory can be made to be stable, so that a single bubble will
>   expand and collapse over and over again in a periodic fashion,
>   emitting a burst of light each time it collapses. For this to occur, a
>   standing acoustic wave is set up within a liquid, and the bubble will
>   sit at a pressure anti-node of the standing wave.
>   The frequencies of resonance depend on the shape and size of the
>   container in which the bubble is contained.

This definition is as quoted in Wikipedia. 
But there is more to that. The main thing is the rate at which the pressure drops and the rate of collapse of bubble. This highly increases the temperature of the bubble and due to large production of heat, it appears as light. The main thing is that the sound be **ultrasonic**. The bubble found when this sound hits water they produce a bubble which has much lower pressure than the regular one. This collapses them increasing their internal pressure to a large extent and their surface temperature higher than the surface of the sun and this heat appears as light.
[Mechanism of Sonoluminescence](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanism_of_sonoluminescence?wprov=sfla1)
This article explains it deeply.